# CouchBase Lite Filter Replication sequencing/ordering

Tags: ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have a server-side filter (javascript: `function(doc, req)`) setup which checks the document type and returns true or false for replication status. I have a scenario where I have to check content of a document say DocumentA in order to decide whether to replicate DocumentB. But there is no sequence in which the `doc` are passed to the javascript. e.g. DocumentB can arrive for syncing before DocumentA, at this point I don't know what to `return` without the knowledge of DocumentA. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you configuring this server-side filter? As far as I was aware, sync gateway doesn't have any ability to write custom replication filters server side. It only supports sync_gateway/bychannel and _doc_ids. See filter param here: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/database-public/get-changes/index.html

Comment: Further, Couchbase lite only supports client-side filters or the channels & doc ids. see: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/replication/replication/index.html

Comment: I'm using filtered replication not sync_gateway. Filters functions is in design document

Comment: Does that mean you are replicating from Couchdb or something else, rather than couchbase? I was under the impression the only way to replicate couchbase lite with couchbase was sync_gateway.

Comment: Can you clarify, as per @MarkGlasgow's questions?  You've tagged this for Couchbase Lite and Sync Gateway.  The docs are clear on what your options are for filtering when going from CBL->SG->Couchbase server.  This isn't about what's possible on the server-side only, but how it integrates with CBL.

Answer (score 0):

First, about filtering.  You can filter by channel and document ID.  Here's the relevant section from the [docs](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html) (as of v1.2):

> Replications can have filters that restrict what documents they'll transfer. This can be useful to limit the amount of a large remote database that's downloaded to a device, or to keep some local documents private. A special type of filter used with the Couchbase Sync Gateway is the set of channels that a pull replication will download from. It's also possible to limit a replication to an explicit set of document IDs.

Based on your description, one solution might be to set up a channel for the particular doc type (your DocumentA), and another for your other docs.  Then, use one-shot replications to guarantee ordering.